# How to access parameter in base url in Swagger + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger

I have a application which is Swagger First and code is generated by `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` using `spring` generator.

I have variable in the server url as below (`{tenant-domain}`).

```
servers:
  - url: https://{host-name}/t/{tenant-domain}/api/
```

Paths begin after this and I have no issue in accessing path parameters using the generated code.

```
paths:
  /{org-uuid}/status
```

How can I access the {tenant-domain} parameter in the base URL?

I would like to use the generated code as it is without modifying manually because if I do that, I have to modify it at every maven code build.

(I know I can modify the code manually and add the `tenant-domain` parameter to the which ever the method I need it. But I was hoping a mechanism without manually modifying the generated code.)

Thanks in advance.